# ActionScript - Eclipse/FlashBuilder: How do I change the color of/prevent the selection of matching selected text?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript, background-color, flash-builder

Within FlashBuilder/Eclipse, when you select a word, such as "protected" or a variable, every instance of that word is also highlighted.

How do I change the background color of the selected instances of that word or disable the feature altogether?

I have already changed the "selected text background color", the instance background color seems to be controlled separately.

Answer (score 4):

Answering this because I was looking for the same thing and treed's answer helped me find it. I found the option at Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations and select "Actionscript Occurrences" and select the color there.

Comment: Is this for FlashBuilder in particular?  My answer was for Eclipse, and FlashBuilder is a plugin for (or is heavily based on) Eclipse.  I don't know the particulars for FlashBuilder, but I know my way around Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

It's the "Mark Occurrences" button.  It looks like a highlighter.  Alt+Shift+O is the shortcut.  It's about in the middle of the toolbar, next to Breadcrumb and Block Selection mode.  (This is on Linux, but probably the same on Windows).  Not sure how to change the color, though.